# How do you do an upsert in CQL?

Tags: cql, upsert

How do you do an UPSERT in CQL. I am finding conflicting information online. Is it possible to do an upsert with just an UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. CQL processes an `UPDATE` as an **upsert** as stated [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html#Description)

> UPDATE writes one or more column values to a row in a Cassandra table.
> Like INSERT, UPDATE is an upsert operation: if the specified row does
> not exist, the command creates it. All UPDATEs within the same
> partition key are applied atomically and in isolation.

```
UPDATE cycling.cyclists
SET firstname = 'Anna', lastname = 'VAN DER BREGGEN'
WHERE id = e7cd5752-bc0d-4157-a80f-7523add8dbcd;
```

An important note that unlike the `INSERT` command, the `UPDATE` command supports counters. Otherwise, the UPDATE and INSERT operations are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all writes are upserts because Cassandra does not perform a read-before-write so it doesn't care if the data exists in the table or not -- it just inserts a new column/row/partition. The exceptions include [lightweight transactions](https://www.datastax.com/blog/lightweight-transactions-cassandra-20) and the [upcoming] [ACID transactions](https://thenewstack.io/an-apache-cassandra-breakthrough-acid-transactions-at-scale/) (in C* 5.0).

When you issue an `UPDATE`, the data is inserted regardless of whether it exists.

Note that all writes (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements) are INSERTs under the hood because Cassandra doesn't do a read-before-write. And yes, `DELETE` statements perform INSERTs of tombstone markers behind the scenes whether the data to be deleted exists or not.